# sklearn SGDClassifier logloss shoots up suddenly at iteration 858

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, logistic-regression

I am using sklearn's SGDClassifier with log loss function to perform logistic regression.

```
 model = sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier(random_state=0, verbose=1,loss='log',n_iter=iterat)    
result = model.fit(X, y)
```

I set verbose=1 to see how the errors look like.

The model seems like it was going to converge at iteration 858 (logloss = 0.1562) but the logloss suddenly shot up again to a very high value

> Epoch 856
>   Norm: 5.19, NNZs: 104, Bias: -1.158471, T: 4280000000, Avg. loss: 0.156228
>   Total training time: 2186.96 seconds.
>
> Epoch 857
>   Norm: 5.19, NNZs: 104, Bias: -1.158562, T: 4285000000, Avg. loss: 0.156217
>   Total training time: 2189.51 seconds.
>
> Epoch 858
>   Norm: 5.19, NNZs: 104, Bias: -1.158651, T: 4290000000, Avg. loss: 0.156205
>   Total training time: 2192.06 seconds.
>
> Epoch 859
>   Norm: 5.19, NNZs: 104, Bias: -1.158744, T: 32704, Avg. loss: 20512.848380
>   Total training time: 2194.61 seconds.
>
> Epoch 860
>   Norm: 5.19, NNZs: 104, Bias: -1.158834, T: 5032704, Avg. loss: 133.443993
>   Total training time: 2197.16 seconds.
>
> Epoch 861
>   Norm: 5.19, NNZs: 104, Bias: -1.158925, T: 10032704, Avg. loss: 67.012436
>   Total training time: 2199.71 seconds.

Does someone know why this is happening? thanks in advance

Comment: Hard to answer without the data. The much more important question is: do you know what ```n_iter``` means? (**epochs!**; i think you are a bit extensive here which might be a reason for this behaviour) And why are you using sgd instead of classic logreg optimization-approaches? (data-size? looks not that huge when one iteration is done within 2 secs)